# Elasticsearch view indexed data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have filter which replace characters

```
                        char_filter:
                            lt_characters:
                                type: mapping
                                mappings: ["a=>bbbbbb", "c=>tttttt", "ddddddd=>k" ]
```

I'm add this filter to index, now how to check does this filter work, where I can found indexed data ?

I mean exactly view replacments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what tokens are created with your `char_filter` you can use the [Analyze API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?char_filters=lt_characters' -d 'this is a test'
```